# Loading CvHaarClassifierCascade from XML

Tags: android, opencv, javacv, javacpp

I am trying to load the `haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml` file from the Android assets with the following piece of code:

```
File file = loadCascadeClassifierFile(context);
    if (file.exists()) {
        return new CvHaarClassifierCascade(cvLoad(file.getAbsolutePath());
    }else {
        throw new FileNotFoundException("File not found.");
    }
```

The loadCascadeClassifierFile does its work and returns a file which contains the xml but it breaks down at

`CvHaarClassifierCascade(cvLoad(file.getAbsolutePath());`

The exception is:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myapp.facerecognition.facerecognition/com.myapp.facerecognition.facerecognition.activity.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: /home/saudet/projects/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/opencv/cppbuild/android-arm/opencv-2.4.11/modules/core/src/persistence.cpp:5113: error: (-204) Could not find the/an object in file storage in function void* cvLoad(char const*, CvMemStorage*, char const*, char const**)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2412)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2470)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:174)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1307)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5593)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I am already stuck at this problem for a while. Did someone ever solved this?

Comment: This is what this bit from the README.md file is for: `// Preload the opencv_objdetect module to work around a known bug.
        Loader.load(opencv_objdetect.class);`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this following code can work:

```
File file = loadCascadeClassifierFile(context);
if (file.exists()) {
    CvHaarClassifierCascade* classifer = (CvHaarClassifierCascade*)cvLoad(file.getAbsolutePath();
    return *classifer;
}else {
    throw new FileNotFoundException("File not found.");
}
```

Comment: Aren't you just trying to make an cpp object through javacode? That's not possible. Won't compile :(